# React with typescript defining useState type, as an object with string key/value pairs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

In React with typescript I am trying to define the useState type as an object with key/value pairs which are strings. I can't find an answer on SO thought I would add it.

I have tried this `<{ [key: string]: string }>>` and some similar variations but not managed to crack it yet.

Comment: use `Record<string, string>`

Answer (score 0):

So this worked -> `useState<{ [key: string]: string }>` :-)

Rubber ducking at its finest! at least its here now for anyone else